# Imputation vs Deletion for Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, imputation

I have a dataset consisting of 17K rows in total for apple mobile games, I want to create a machine learning model that predicts the number of ratings, i.e. popularity of the game, one of the columns I have is in-app purchases which contain values similar to [0], [1.99,9.99], etc. However, around 9K rows have null values, Is it better to remove the rows with null values or use imputation techniques like KNN, or maybe just remove the column altogether, I am leaning towards KNN but I feel that since the % of missing values is high it can lead to other problems.

Thank you in advance

So far I removed the 9k rows with null values and the preliminary results look fine, however, I feel removing 50% of the dataset has a high opportunity cost and would rather keep these rows.

Answer (score 0):

Removing all the rows containing missing values is not suggested specially in this case as you are discarding more then half of the data. Try using imputation techniques but since there are more then 50% missing values you can also think about discarding the feature as imputation techniques may not work well. Check for feature importance and then either use imputation techniques or remove the feature. [Imputation methods](https://towardsdatascience.com/7-ways-to-handle-missing-values-in-machine-learning-1a6326adf79e)